# Method Miscalculation

Tags: java, methods

I am having trouble understanding a calculation within my code. I have done one method for addition in this mini calculator I am making. This is purely to practice methods. I created the first method for addition and for some reason when I select the option to add two numbers together and the program goes in to the method and returns an answer it does a multiplication instead of an addition.

The code is below for the whole program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Testing {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner userReader = new Scanner(System.in);
int number1;
int number2;
int decision;
int result = 0;

System.out.println("Please input your first number");
 number1 = userReader.nextInt();
 System.out.println("Please input your second number");
 number2 = userReader.nextInt();

 System.out.println("Please select what you would like to do");
 System.out.println("1.Addition");
 System.out.println("2.Subtraction");
 System.out.println("3.Division");
 System.out.println("4.Multiplication");
 decision = userReader.nextInt();

 switch(decision)
 {
 case 1 : result = Addition(number1,number2);
 case 2 : result = number1 - number2;
 case 3 : result = number1 / number2;
 case 4 : result = number1 * number2;
 }



 System.out.println("Your answer is " + result);


}
public static int Addition(int number1, int number2) {
    int Additionresult;

    Additionresult = number1 + number2;

    return Additionresult;


}

    }
```

Best Regards

Comment: You forgot the `break;` at the end of a case.

Comment: Wow... I suck o.o. Thank you so much.

Comment: you need to use `break;` see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)

Answer (score 3):

In addition, it is good practice to add a default so that if the user enters a number other than 1, 2, 3, or 4 you can let the user know they have entered an invalid option.

Example:

switch (decision)
{
   case 1:
    ....;
    break;
   case 2:
    ....;
    break;
   case 3:
    ....;
    break;
   case 4:
    ....;
    break;
   default:
    System.out.println("Invalid option");
    break;
}

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the `break` after each `case`.